# Binary searching for string arrays

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

How do I sort an array of string for binary search. Below I always recieve a minus number for my index instead of the correct index. Please help? If the word is not in the array -1 should be returned.

```
  public static int binary (String [] theword, String a) {
    int index = -1;
        Arrays.sort(theword);
        Arrays.toString(theword);
        index = Arrays.binarySearch(theword, a);
    return index;

}
```

Comment: Checked the code and it is returning correct result for my test data. Can you share the value you are passing?

Comment: @prashant I am reading in a file and then searching for the word.  I look for he word "to" and it returns back -11 instead of 11

Comment: can you change your code to output the contents of the array, and `a`, and then post the output here

Comment: Are you sure "to" is in the file you're reading? Are you sure that word is being inserted into the array? Per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), a negative number means the object is not found (and gives the index where it would be).

Comment: Can you post the code where you are parsing the file and forming the string array?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard yes I print the array out before searching, its there. Tried more than one word still coming up minus

Comment: Can you post the output when you run your code?

Answer (score 3):

It works, see below

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String words[] = { "abc3", "abc2", "abc1", "abc4" };

    Arrays.sort(words);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
    {
        String word = "abc3";
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(words, word);
        index = index >= 0 ? index : -1;
        System.out.println(word + " = " + index);
    }
    {
        String word = "abc11";
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(words, word);
        index = index >= 0 ? index : -1;
        System.out.println(word + " = " + index);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[abc1, abc2, abc3, abc4]
abc3 = 2
abc11 = -1
```

You return the index from the sorted array while you need an index from the original array.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that the return value for [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29) is as follows:

> **Returns:**
>   index of the search key, if it is contained in the array;
>   otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as
>   the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index
>   of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements
>   in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this
>   guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key
>   is found.

So clearly your word "to" was not found by binary search. Moreover, had it existed, it would have been in the 10th index of this array. As `-(10) -1 == -11`

There is a good possibility that you are searching for the word `to` however the data in the array contains the word `to` with some spaces around it giving you the undesired, yet correct, result of binary search.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake that I have seen is a space being added to the word in question. Apply the trim() function on each word before adding to your array.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this as well. Can't know for sure unless we see more of the code/output.

Comment: @prashant this is the problem but how do i apply it to the method above. I used trim when i was storing them in the array but it dosn't work when it is passed into a method

Comment: Does a manual linear search find `to`? I doubt it would if the java official binary search method can't find it. You only need to trim things once. Trimming before putting into the array is all you need to do.